# Xpages Rest Service Control "Keys" Properties dont works as expected with special Characters like ö Ö Ä ä ü Ü ß

Tags: rest, api, filter, key, xpages

I am using Rest Service to load the list of data using provided JSON by rest services, Setting Up columns , Loading dynamic view all works fine, But I observed that the "Keys" foe filter i am using as a search in front End.

I have 2 Views , One is sorted by NAME and other is Sorted by Number. So in both cases the one with numbers the keys returns the matches as expected, But in the Other view in which the sorted column is by names as I search for **Mühlhaus** 
The results are the exact search for example.
**Mühlhaus**

But the fact is there are other further entries like

**Mühlhausen**

**Mühlhauserr**

**Mühlhausor**

are simple ignored. Now the most pointing thing is is I put keys **Müh**, The result is Simply Nothing. Similarly other example. I add Keys **Göbb** . Only one result appears as shown in Image.

This is the Entries in the View for **Göbb**

[image]

I found the result via keys Filter is only one Entry.

[image]

I also changed the setting in XSP.property file for encoding UTF-8 , But doesnt Helps.

I have an xpage named **api_loader.xsp** with Rest Service with all columns configured and also view name I am grabbing from URL , Similarly the Keys are also grabbed from url Parameter , the source code for the rest api is

```
<xe:this.service>
            <xe:viewItemFileService contentType="application/json"
                count="20000">
                <xe:this.columns>
                    <xe:restViewColumn value="test" name="column1">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column1");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>

                    </xe:restViewColumn>

                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column2">


                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column2");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>
                    </xe:restViewColumn>




                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column3">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column3");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>


                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column4">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column4");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>


                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column5">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column5");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>


                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column6">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column6");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>


                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column7">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column7");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>


                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column8">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column8");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>


                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column9">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column9");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>


                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column10">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column10");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>


                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column11">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column11");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>


                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column12">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column12");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>


                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column13">


                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column13");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>

                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column14">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column14");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>

                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column15">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column15");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>


                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="ReservedBy"
                        columnName="ReservedBy">


                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="afIcon"
                        columnName="faIcon">



                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="attachment"
                        columnName="attachment">

                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="PID" columnName="Ref">

                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                    <xe:restViewColumn columnName="faIcon2"
                        name="afIcon2">
                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                </xe:this.columns>

                <xe:this.viewName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("aView");
if(urlParam == ""){

}
else{
return urlParam;
}}]]></xe:this.viewName>
                <xe:this.start><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("more_from");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.start>
                <xe:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("searchKeys");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.keys>
                <xe:this.parentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("PARENTID");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.parentId>
            </xe:viewItemFileService>
        </xe:this.service>
    </xe:restService>
```

The URL some how looks like

[http://domainname/database.nsf/api_loader.xsp/ve_entry?aView=versicherte&attachment=attachment&PID=Ref&column1=title&column2=telnumber&column3=created&searchKeys=Mühlhaus](http://domainname/database.nsf/api_loader.xsp/ve_entry?aView=versicherte&attachment=attachment&PID=Ref&column1=title&column2=telnumber&column3=created&searchKeys=M%C3%BChlhaus)

Edit- Just Found out that also if I try to find with **Mue** the results in json also returns **Mü** starting words.

Cannot guess howit is working on.

Note:- This Views Contains More the 300000 Documents.

Any Kind of suggestions will be appretiated

Comment: Please show us relevant parts of your code. Also, perhaps you need to encode your search term before submitting.

Comment: I have edited the question with the code of the Rest service and also the url m calling this service

Comment: I have tried encoding to UTF-8 as per you instruction but no luck , its the same.

Comment: Look for "Accent sensitive sorting" of key column.

Comment: Yes I tried it, if i check the Accent sensitive sorting option , it works like if I search for "Mühlhaus" , Result is "Mühlhausen ", "Mühlhauser", "Mühlhauseur" but the "Mühlhaus" is the record also exist but not displayed

Comment: in your picture the view doesn’t seem to be sorted, did you take the picture whilst the view was sorted by another column?

Comment: I have another view where first column is numbers which is sorted ascending work perfect, the image which is added this column is also a sorted column